# Kills java process after few minutes [Linux Ubuntu VPS]

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, process

I got an runescape private server and I wanted to host my server on it. I ran it with screen like this: `screen java -Xmx815m -cp bin:data/libs/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar:data/libs/FileStore.jar:data/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar:data/libs/RuneTopListV2.1.jar:data/libs/GTLVote.jar com.rs.Launcher`

It works fine but after some few seconds or minutes the process just gets killed. Why does that happen? Its weird... Its very important for me to fix it so I can start hosting the server.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `java` call into a bash script and running that with `&`? I have had issues with, for example, user processes being closed with an ssh tunnel collapses.

Comment: @Kyle I do not got any error.

Comment: @Boris the Spider What you mean with a bash script?

Comment: Something like 2. [here](http://floppix.ccai.com/scripts1.html) but with `java -Xmx815m...` rather than whatever it does. Then `chmod +x` it and run it with `./myScript&`

Comment: @BoristheSpider That is what the screen command does.  It executes your program in a detachable terminal that you can reattach to and disconnect from at will.

Comment: Are there any log files at all?  Maybe try just launching without screen altogether to see if maybe you are getting an error that prints to STDOUT, but then screen exits and clears the screen?

Comment: @Boris the Spider I ran the server with the bash script but now I got another problem... If I close the SSH client, the server will turn off. I need to make that the process will still run even tho I disconnect from the vps.

Comment: @CodeChimp If I launch server without screen, my server will turn off if I close the SSH client. How can I get the server on while I am disconnected from the vps?

Comment: Managed to fix that :) I did `nohup bash run.sh`

Comment: @HolySymbol The purpose of executing outside of screen is to see any error output that might happen.  I have seen many of times where applications will silently exit screen (newznab's update scripts, for instance) and you never see the output.  It's not meant as a long-term solution to running the application.  For your nohup solution, keep in mind any output by the application will get written to nohup.out, so you will need to manually clean that file.

Comment: @CodeChimp Alright. I actually got an error right now. `run.sh: line 2: 19191 Killed`

Comment: Do you see any errors in /var/messages or dmesg?

Comment: I got that error inside nohup.out

Comment: What does line 2 of run.sh do?  I am guessing that is the line that runs the application, and it probably exited abnormally.

Comment: You should add your new findings to the question (`edit`) so other people don't have to read through the comments. Also as @CodeChimp said, are there any messages in `/var/log/*` or `/var/messages` or `dmesg`?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `nohup` to your run.sh file instead of using `screen`. If you do want to use `screen`, try to search for the parameters it needs to run correctly.

(there's a tutorial out there on rune-server, have seen it multiple times when I was searching how to get my RSPS online on centos a few days ago!)

See the [man page for nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).

Comment: nohup is a good Idea for that problem. Maybe add link to man page?